# Open view controller from AppDelegate using SWRevealViewController and UIStoryBoard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, sidebar, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm starting to rewrite an existing project using SWRevealViewController and more specifically using the sample code RevealControllerStoryboardExample as the framework.

Here is the link with the SideBarRevealController : https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

I have the requirement where I want to open a particular view controller from the AppDelegate.m file as I use a URL scheme.

Here is the relevant section in AppDelegate.m.  It doesn't actually open the view controller.

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {    
    // Get the view controller
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewController"];
    // Swap out the Front view controller and display
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.revealViewController setFrontViewController:vc];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the most up to date version of SWRevealViewController? Looks like 2.0 has support for pushFrontViewController:animated: . Also, you don't need to reference the AppDelegate like you do when you're in it already. self.window.rootViewController should work ;)

Comment: @jyap Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Shantanu um, it was such a long time ago I ended up not using UIStoryboard. :)